# Selecting only elements inside same row

Tags: jquery, html

I am making calculation table with div elements rather than td and tr. Each row of the table should do the math based on imput field entry.

```
<div id="pricelist_table">
    <div class="table_header">
        <div id="model">Model</div>
        <div id="exw">EXW Also</div>
        <div id="vat">VAT</div>
        <div id="msrp">MSRP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table_body">
        <div class="model">XG-C100C</div>
        <div class="exw-price">1</div>
        <div class="without-vat">1</div>
        <div class="msrp-entry"><input class="msrp-data" name="msrp-info" placeholder="enter data"></div>
    <div class="table_body">
        <div class="model">PL-AC56 KIT</div>
        <div class="exw-price">1</div>
        <div class="without-vat">1</div>
        <div class="msrp-entry"><input class="msrp-data" name="msrp-info" placeholder="enter data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have Jquery like this, bit it is catching all rows.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){   
   $( ".msrp-data" ).keypress(function() {
    var msrp = $(".msrp-data").val();
    var vat =  25;
    var result = msrp * vat;
    $(".exw-price").html(result);
    });
});
```

End idea is to calculate each row separatly only when data is entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the handler for `.msrp-data` you can refer to `$(this)` for the same field. To get the value of *other* fields in the row you need to scope them (for example using `$(this).closest(".table_body")`):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){   
   $( ".msrp-data" ).keypress(function() {
    var msrp = +$(this).val();
    var vat =  25;
    var result = msrp * vat;
    $(".exw-price",$(this).closest(".table_body")).html(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pricelist_table">
    <div class="table_header">
        <div id="model">Model</div>
        <div id="exw">EXW Also</div>
        <div id="vat">VAT</div>
        <div id="msrp">MSRP</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table_body">
        <div class="model">XG-C100C</div>
        <div class="exw-price">1</div>
        <div class="without-vat">1</div>
        <div class="msrp-entry"><input class="msrp-data" name="msrp-info" placeholder="enter data"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="table_body">
        <div class="model">PL-AC56 KIT</div>
        <div class="exw-price">1</div>
        <div class="without-vat">1</div>
        <div class="msrp-entry"><input class="msrp-data" name="msrp-info" placeholder="enter data"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Note you were also missing a closing `</div>` on the first `table_body` row!)

Comment: I recommend using `.closest(".table_body")` rather than `.parent().parent()`, so you're not so dependent on the specific nesting depth.

Comment: @Barmar yes, much better.

Comment: Thank you both! Working as intended!